# Virtualbox from apt does not detect most of my CPUs

Tags: apt, virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Virtualbox installed with sudo apt-get install virtualbox runs fine, but throws error:

```
VERR_INVALID_CPU_ID (-1018) - Invalid Virtual CPU ID
```

When running a VM. Checking the source I find:

```
#define VERR_INVALID_CPU_ID                 (-1018)
/** Too many VCPUs. */
```

Going into the settings it appears that Virtualbox thinks I only have 2 CPUs, when I have 24. What's going on here?

I currently don't have VX-t on this machine (I don't think it supports it, at least based on the results of kvm-ok) but from the information I could find VX-t isn't necessary for Virtualbox to run a VM. Shouldn't it crash if it absolutely requires Vx-t on?

Added Quirk: Bios says virtualization technologies are in fact activated. So now we have an additional mystery.

Some other posts imply the apt version is broken and I absolutely need to reinstall from Oracle. I want to hear from Ubuntu: Should the version from apt-get be working? Do I absolutely need Vx-t on?

Comment: I have always had the best luck using the ppa ... https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/virtualbox.org_contrib

Answer (score 0):

The user manual for VirtualBox states hardware virtualization must be enabled for SMP to function properly.

```
Even though VirtualBox does not always require hardware virtualization, enabling it is required in
the following scenarios:

    VirtualBox’s  64-bit  guest  support  (added  with  version  2.0)  and  multiprocessing  (SMP,
    added with version 3.0) both require hardware virtualization to be enabled.  (This is not
    much of a limitation since the vast majority of today’s 64-bit and multicore CPUs ship with
    hardware virtualization anyway; the exceptions to this rule are e.g. older Intel Celeron and
    AMD Opteron CPUs.)
```

Perhaps your BIOS supports hardware virtualization but your CPU doesn't?